# Baidu browser unable to connect due to error 137

Tags: internet, browser, chromium

I am having trouble with Baidu (previously Spark) browser.

Everything is ok with both Chrome and Firefox, but with Baidu browser I am getting the error message:

> "Baidu Browser meet an internet error" error 137.

Can anyone help with this problem please?

Comment: Hi Ali Masri, welcome to Super User. Can you edit your question to provide any more information on your problem? As it stands, there is not a lot to go on. I have also suggested an edit to improve the formatting and change the tags associated with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Baidu Browser (until end of 2014 formerly Spark; not to be confused with the other Browser called Spark) appears to be based on Chromium:

> It's based on the Chromium platform, which makes it speedy, lightweight and customizable.

A quick search for error 137 suggests it is `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED`, with a plethora of potential fixes.

Since I myself haven't experienced this problem, do any of the following **at your own risk**:

- reinstall Baidu Browser (some places suggest registry entries may play a part in this; my guess is that an un/reinstall may help here but really it's possibly)
- malware check: follow your own protocol for this (MBAB, Spybot S&D ccleaner, etc)
- winsock reset: from an admin `cmd.exe` prompt, run `netsh winsock reset`, then restart (this is often suggested for other oddball connection issues)
- disable NetBIOS on DHCP Server (as per [knowledgebase kb313314](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313314))

These fixes may be incorrect; I am working on the assumption that because BB is based on Chromium the underlying components (and therefore fixes<sup>[1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tpBfLA3BQg4)</sup><sup>[2](http://www.reginout.com/error-137.html)</sup>) are similar.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes I previously tried the above options but the problem persists.

Comment: @AliMasri Have you read the linked posts in [1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tpBfLA3BQg4) and [2](http://www.reginout.com/error-137.html)? They expand a bit on what to try. As my original comment said, more information would b helpful; this answer is speculation at this point.

Comment: Yes I already did, I really don't know what more information can be given. I just can access the internet from all the browsers except baidu. I ran CCleaner, reset the logs, disabled the NETBIOS, etc. and still doesn't work.

Comment: @AliMasri You should edit your question to include those things which you have tried as that is very relevant information (as per 'Search and research' in [How to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

I have recently experienced the same problem with my Baidu Browser, I searched the Internet for answers but nothing suggested helped, I sent a contact to the Baidu home site, Including a screenshot of the error message.

I then decided to see if I could Find another browser like baidu, during this search I attempted to go to a site to view another browser, and was stopped from accessing the site(I was using torch browser for this search), I then noticed at the bottom of the block notice, that I had been blocked by an Antivirus program called Sophos Antivirus, at the time I believed that I had uninstalled this program, on thinking about this it occurred to me that I had installed this program about the time the error 137 message started occurring, I immediately uninstalled this program, after which I was told to restart my computer, when my computer had rebooted, I tried Baidu browser again, It started working just fine.

I suggest you look at anything you may have recently installed, like possibly antivirus programs or specific virus removal programs, you could try a system restore back to a date before the problem started to occur, this would remove any programs you have installed that might be conflicting with your Baidu Browser. good luck and I hope this helps

John D.

P.S. Strangely there was no message to tell me that Sophos Antivirus was blocking the Baidu Browser, and it never affected the other three browsers I run (Internet explorer 9, Google Chrome, or my Torch Browser) very strange problem?.

Bye and Goodluck. - John D

Comment: This does not even begin to answer the proposed question.

Comment: Avira Antivirus also reported Baidu browser has a virus: [Is Baidu Spark browser dangerous and harmful on my computer?](https://answers.avira.com/en/question/is-baidu-spark-browser-dangerous-and-harmful-on-my-computer--15805)